Issues writing files with pySpark (pyarrow not found even though it is found in active python environment)
first time poster long time lurker.  I'm attempting to learn pySpark and its all working well with the exception I can't write out any files using pyspark.  Whenever I try to write a dataframe out to a .csv or a .parquet file an error similar to below is thrown.
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o71.csv. : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)
All other pyspark commands are executing without issue.
I found a testing script on the Spark website (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/testing_pyspark.html) and when I run the script found there, it throws an error:
ImportError: PyArrow >= 4.0.0 must be installed; however, it was not found.
However when I pip list my environment it indicates I have pyarrow 11.0.0 installed.
I'm running on a windows 11 environment with Hadoop 3.5.1, java version 22 2024-03-19 and Python 3.9.18. I'm also running Jupyter notebooks Version: 7.0.8
I've used both of the following in an attempt to write out the data frame
df.write.mode('overwrite').csv('test')
df.write.partitionBy("date_built").mode("overwrite").parquet("test_partitioned")

both lines throw an error but also successfully create folders in my working directory named test or test_partioned but no file is written.
Further the same script runs on google colab without issue creating the requested files.

maybe you have two Pythons installed and you run code with one Python but you check modules with other Python - but Pythons don't share modules. In code you can use print( sys.executable ) to see /full/path/to/python and later use this /full/path/to/python -m pip ... to check installed modules and eventually install missing module.

your jupyter python kernel might be different than the one on the terminal.

Thanks @furas for the response and suggestion.  I only have one python intalled but I followed your instructions anyway... and when I run pip list using the full path provided by the sys.excecutable method it indicates pyarrow 11.0.0 is installed
